# How to get the value of a callback function from an Ajax request

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, callback

This question is maybe related to the question i asked here: [Jquery ajax request with async:true does not return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618517/jquery-ajax-request-with-asynctrue-does-not-return-value).

Now, i'm facing another problem. How do i retrieve the value from the callback function?

```
 function find_bus_route(array_bustops,callback){

            $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
                async: true,
            url: 'find_routenum.php',

            data:{

                array_bustops:JSON.stringify(array_bustops)

            },
            dataType:'json', //html,xml

            success: function(my_results){

                callback(my_results);

            },

            error:function(x,e){
                if(x.status==0){
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                }else if(x.status==404){
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
                }
            }


        });

    }//end function

var arr_one;

    find_bus_route(arr_bus,function (data){
                                                                                 arr_one=data;
          alert(arr_one) //has correct value        

    }

alert (arr_one) //-->This returns undefined..
```

arr_one seems to be out of scope.

```
if(arr_one == arr_two){
   //do something.

}
```

actually what i'm trying to do is this:
assuming there is no callback and async is set to false and the function find_bus_route is returning a value.

```
var arr_one=find_bus_route(arr_stop1);
var arr_two=find_bus_route(arr_stop2);

if(arr_one==arr_two){
 //do something

}
else {
//do something


 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you call an external page aynchronously, you do not have the result immediately (depending on server/network load).

In your code, the second alert (which displays `undefined`) is executed just after the AJAX call (response might not be obtained). The other one is executed when the JSON response is fetched. You can use return value only in `success` callback.

I think you should explain us exactly what are you trying to do.

**EDIT :**
I think what you need is called *deferred object*, see [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).
With [`jQuery.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/#example-0) you can wait for two asynchronous calls. The first example is exactly what you ask. In the *when* callback, you compare the two results.

Answer (score 2):

First "A" in ajax is for asynchronous. The ajax hasn't completed when your "if" fires. You need to move it into your success callback